Can the alternating operator be defined for distributions in a compatible way?
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The alternating operator $A$ can be defined as follows:
$$Af(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \textrm{sgn}(\sigma) f(x_{\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(n)}) \tag{1}$$
or more generally if $g \in \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$A(f\otimes g) = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{m!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n + m}} \textrm{sgn}(\sigma)f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n)})g(x_{\sigma(n+1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n+m)})$$
Can this operator be extended in any meaningful way to a distribution so that it is compatible with the definition (1)?
I am looking for a definition that can be obtained by passing the operator from the distribution to the test functions as is usually done with distributions (e.g. Fourier transforms or weak derivatives of distributions) such as
$$\langle A(F \times G), f \otimes g\rangle = \langle F\otimes G, A(f\otimes g)\rangle. \tag{2}$$
As an example take $k = 2$ and let $F$ and $G$ be two distributions (for concreteness we can take $F \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $G \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^m)$). Then a definition I thought of is
$$A(F\otimes G)(f,g) = \frac{1}{2}\Big(F(f)G(g) - F(g)G(f)\Big). \tag{3}$$
Then we have
$$\begin{align}\langle F\otimes G, A(f\otimes g)\rangle =& F\otimes G\Big(\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{m!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n + m}} \textrm{sgn}(\sigma)f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n)})g(x_{\sigma(n+1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n+m)}) \Big)\\
=&\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{m!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n + m}} F\big(f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n)})\big)G\big(g(x_{\sigma(n+1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n+m)})\big)
\end{align}$$
but it's not clear how to proceed form here to get compatibility such as (2). Can this be done or will my definition (3) have to be modified?

What are $k$ and $\ell$?

@P.P.Tuong It's supposed to be $n$ and $m$. Thanks for catching that.

The right hand side of (3) doesn't include all permutations of the coordinates. Shouldn't it rather be something like this?
$$\frac{1}{2}\Big(AF(f)AG(g) - AF(g)AG(f)\Big)$$
Note that if $F\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R),$ then $AF(f)=F(f).$

@md2perpe Thanks for your comment. By $AF(f)AG(g)$ do you mean $$AF(g)AG(g) = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{m!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n + m}} F\big(f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n)})\big)G\big(g(x_{\sigma(n+1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n+m)})\big)?$$ If so, how does this imply $AF(f)=F(f)$? Wouldn't we have something like $$AF(g) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}} F\big(f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots x_{\sigma(n)})\big)?$$

I wrote "if $F\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R),$ i.e. $n=1.$ Then we have $AF(f)=F(f)$ since there are just one permutation of a single variable.

I realized, though, that if $m\neq n$ then expressions like $\frac{1}{2}\Big(F(f)G(g) - F(g)G(f)\Big)$ do not work. In the second term, $F$ takes a function on an $n$-dimensional space but is given a function on an $m$-dimensional space.

@md2perpe You're right, my definition doesn't work. I suppose we cannot define the alternating operator so that $$\langle A(F \times G), f \otimes g\rangle = \langle F\otimes G, A(f\otimes g)\rangle$$ because of what you mentioned in your comment. However it seems it is true that $\langle A(F), f \rangle = \langle F, A(f)\rangle$ more or less by definition?

Yes, $\langle A(F), f \rangle = \langle F, A(f)\rangle$ is true if $F$ is given by an $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ function, and works as a definition for $A(F).$

@md2perpe Thank you for your help!
